# How to return a dymamic array of user data types in Lotusscript funtion

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have this userdefined data type:

```
Type Image
  Filename As String
  Label As String
End Type
```

And I want to create a function that can return an array of images. So far I have created this:

```
Function GetImages() As Variant
  Dim images(1) As Image

  Dim image0 As Image
  image0.Filename = "test0.txt"
  image0.Label = "test0"

  Dim image1 As Image
  image1.Filename = "test1.txt"
  image1.Label = "test1"

  images(0) = image0
  images(1) = image1

  GetImages = images
End Function
```

The line "GetImages = images" give me this compile error: Type mismatch on: IMAGES

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert an array of Types into a Variant.

Use `Class` instead of `Type`:

```
Class Image
    Public Filename As String
    Public Label As String
End Class

Function GetImages() As Variant
  Dim images(1) As Image

  Dim image0 As New Image
  image0.Filename = "test0.txt"
  image0.Label = "test0"

  Dim image1 As New Image
  image1.Filename = "test1.txt"
  image1.Label = "test1"

  Set images(0) = image0
  Set images(1) = image1

  GetImages = images
End Function
```

You can access class elements like type elements:

```
Dim imgs As Variant
imgs = GetImages()
Print imgs(0).filename
```

Comment: An alternative to using an array is to use a list, especially if the number of elements changes.